# Why do we say ha-motzi before al achilat matzah instead of after?

Tags: blessing, passover-seder-hagada, priorities

I was taught that it's important not to make an interruption between a b'racha and its fulfillment, such that we don't say anything between making *motzi* and eating the bread.  To me the b'racha is "attached" to the bread.

At the seder we say *al achilat matzah* because of the specific mitzvah of eating matzah, but we say it *after motzi*,<sup>1</sup> creating an interruption.  Obviously there's going to be an interruption between *one* of these b'rachot and the eating, but I'm wondering why they're in the order they are.  It seems to me that it would be better to not break up the already-established connection between *motzi* and eating, but Chazal are way more learned than I so I assume there is a reason that I haven't seen on my own.  What is it?

<sup>1</sup> According to Silverman and Artscroll haggadot, and my memory of what we've done in past years.

Comment: You could ask the same question about _Qidush ha-Yom_: We say _Boreh Peri ha-Gefen_ , then before drinking the wine we say _Meqadesh ha-Shabat_ (or _Meqadesh Yisra'el veha-Zemanim_, or do the full _Yain-Qidush-Ner-Havdalah-Zeman_, as appropriate).

Comment: @TamirEvan good point.  I considered the general kiddush case but guessed that since we do that every week that might change the priorities (versus something we only change once a year).  I hadn't thought about your last example; thanks.

Comment: The same question likely applies to making a berakhah on a fruit (Bore Peri HaEtz) and then saying *Shehehhayinu*

Comment: @TamirEvan Also [Hilchot Terumot 15:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/7315.htm#20) ([English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/992041))

Comment: @DoubleAA I chose the example I did because (1) she'd have been more likely to come across it, (2) the interruption is longer, and (3) it's less directly connected with the action to be performed.

Comment: @Lee Some don't do it that way.

Comment: "Obviously there's going to be an interruption between one of these b'rachot and the eating" - why does there have to be?  Why can't we make the first bracha, eat, then make the second and eat again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a concept called "תדיר ושאינו תדיר, תדיר קודם", which loosely translated means "between something frequent and something infrequent, we do the frequent first" (see [Mishna Zevachim 10:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99_%D7%90)).  In this case, since *motsi* is frequent and *al achilat matzah* is infrequent, we say *motsi* first.

The Sixth Lubavitcher Rebbe's [לקוטי טעמים ומנהגים להגדה של פסח](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/hgshp/16) explicitly says this in the context of your question.  He also mentions that it makes sense to first thank Hashem for taking the "bread" out of the earth before making a brachah on matzah that was made therefrom.

Comment: Why is "_Tadir Qodem_" enough of a reason to allow adding a _Berakhah_ between _ha-Motzi_ and the eating of the _Matzah_, for which it was said?

Comment: @TamirEvan The opposite order would have a *berakhah* between *al achilat matzah* and the eating of the *matzah*, for which it is said.

Comment: I missed that point. Thanks for clarifying.